# Prevent Image Scaling on HighDPI Displays

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

As part of a project of mine, I want to write an image-viewer inside a webbrowser.

The images are extracted from video files on the server and sent to the client. The image should be displayed *as is* and not be scaled (unless the user explicitely chose to do so) by the browser, as this would distort the image.

[image: Image showing the Problem.]
This image illustrates the problem. The Win32-Application (with disabled DPI-Scaling) Shows a 20x20 image without any scaling (the black area). Chrome shows the 20x20 image (here a green image) scaled by a factor of two. What I want is that the image on the browser has the same area as the black square inside the Win32-Application, regardless of which DPI-Setting the user has chosen on his system.

To be clear: Serving the user an image with higher resolution **is not an option**. Neither is having the browser scale the image with different Settings acceptable. JavaScript-based solutions however may work as well.

I have not yet been able to find a solution to that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to disable it, but I found something to basically reverse the scaling. ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6rh3wq/does_firefox_have_a_setting_to_disable_dpi/))

```
var factor = 1/window.devicePixelRatio; 
document.querySelector('img').style.transform = 'scale(' + factor + ')';
```

I do not know how accurate this scaling will be and whether the image will still be rendered pixel-perfect. However, assuming the browser does some rounding internally before rendering, it should.

Comment: While it is not exactly what I was searching for, it will do for now. I solved it by setting the width and height attributes instead of scaling the image.